# Restrict form submit if file size is greater unobstrusive validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have to apply file size uplaod validation

```
<input type="file" name="UserModel.Resume" id="UserModel.Resume" class="fileSize" data-val="true" data-val-required="The CV field is required." />
```

and i have a file size checking function,

```
$('.fileSize').bind('change', function () {
        var fileSize = this.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024;
        if (fileSize > 3) {
            $(this).addClass("input-validation-error");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");
        }
    });
```

Is it possible to validatie through a function like

```
data-val-function="SomeFunction()" //Some function which return true if valid else false
```

I want to restrict from submitting the form if file size is greater than 3 MB, any kind of help will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="e.perventDefault(); Validate()?this.forms.submit() : alert('Validation Error!')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/37/

Form will not submit if your input has class `input-validation-error` . Instead it will throw error message.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('click', '.submit', function () {
    var b = $(this);
    var form = b.parents('form:first');
    if (form.find('.input-validation-error').length) {
        alert('error somewhere');
        return false;
    } else {
        //your normal code
    }
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="temp">
    <input type="file" name="UserModel.Resume" id="UserModel.Resume" class="fileSize input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The CV field is required." />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have an object of validation functions:

```
var validationFns = {
    'customValidator': function() {
        // do something
    },
    'customValidator2()': function() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then you can add a data attribute on the method like:

```
data-val-function="customValidator"
```

or

```
data-val-function="customValidator2()"
```

And use the following code:

```
$('.fileSize').bind('change', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var validationFn = $this.attr('data-val-function');
    if (validationFn && $.isFunction(validationFns[validationFn])) {
        if (validationFns[validationFn]()) {
            $this.removeClass('input-validation-error');
        } else {
            $this.addClass('input-validation-error');
        }
    } else {
        var fileSize = this.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024;
        if (fileSize > 3) {
            $this.addClass('input-validation-error');
        } else {
            $this.removeClass('input-validation-error');
        }
    }
});
```